# How can I prevent files in backupdir from overriding similar named files?

Tags: backup

In my vimrc I have:

```
set backupdir=~/.cache/vim/backup |call mkdir(&backupdir, 'p', 0o700)
set undodir=~/.cache/vim/undo     |call mkdir(&undodir,   'p', 0o700)
```

This stores a backup file in `~/.cache/vim/backup` on every write, which is useful if I accidentally remove something, or remove something that I ended up wanting to have later anyway.

The problem is that the filename is just the "basename", that is, both `~/one/README.md` and `~/two/README.md` get written as `~/.cache/vim/backup/README.md`, overwriting any previous file.

This problem doesn't exist for `undodir`, which stores it as two files, with the full pathname:

```
~/.vim/cache/undo/%home%martin%one%README.md
~/.vim/cache/undo/%home%martin%two%README.md
```

How can I keep a unique copy for every pathname, similar to what `undodir` does by default?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you look into `:h 'backupdir'`, you will find in the description:

```
    - For Unix and Win32, if a directory ends in two path separators "//",
      the backup file name will be built from the complete path to the
      file with all path separators changed to percent '%' signs. This
      will ensure file name uniqueness in the backup directory.
      On Win32, it is also possible to end with "\\".  However, When a
      separating comma is following, you must use "//", since "\\" will
      include the comma in the file name. Therefore it is recommended to
      use '//', instead of '\\'.
```

Thus, if you add `//` at the end of the path, it should behave the same as 'undodir':

```
set backupdir=~/.cache/vim/backup// |call mkdir(&backupdir, 'p', 0o700)
```

One example of setting up directories:

```
vim9script

g:vimdata = $'{has("win32") ? expand("$APPDATA") : expand("~/.config")}/vim-data'
if !isdirectory(g:vimdata) | mkdir(g:vimdata, "p") | endif

&directory = expand($'{g:vimdata}/swap/')
&backupdir = expand($'{g:vimdata}/backup//')
&undodir = expand($'{g:vimdata}/undo//')
if !isdirectory(&undodir)   | mkdir(&undodir, "p")   | endif
if !isdirectory(&backupdir) | mkdir(&backupdir, "p") | endif
if !isdirectory(&directory) | mkdir(&directory, "p") | endif

set backup
set undofile
```

Here, I have edited 2 `readme.md` files, one in `~/temp/hello/`  and another in `~/temp/world/` directories:

[image]

Comment: Brilliant; this is much better than my hack! Looks like this was added in 8.1.0251

Answer (score 0):

The best way I could figure out is (abusing) the `backupext` setting for this:

```
au BufWritePre * &backupext = '-' .. substitute(expand('<afile>:p'), '[^a-zA-Z0-9_-]', '%', 'g')
```

This sets it to the dirname before every write, and you end up with two files in ~/.cache/vim/backup:

```
~/.cache/vim/backup/README.md-%home%martin%one%README%md
~/.cache/vim/backup/README.md-%home%martin%two%README%md
```

It's a bit uglier than `undodir`, but still workable enough.

Comment: 1. In this case there's no need to reset extension on every write; could make use of some different autocmd to set it once per buffer lifetime
2. You can apply hash function, e.g. `:h sha256()`, to path string and to get unique numeric extension (actually only few last digits should be enough) instead of that ugly and lengthy thing.

Comment: The problem with sha256() is that it'll be hard to know which file belongs to which path @Matt; you'll end up with 20 `README.md-<some-hash>`. Either way, Maxim's solution is much better.